# Print() keep waiting for the doc to be processed

Tags: c#, printing, printdocument

I want to launch printing, and then after some time verify if the job get processed to cancel it if not. but when i use Print() method it stack on it until the document processed or it launch an exception if i cancel the print job externally in MS OS.

```
PrinterSettings printerSettings = new PrinterSettings();
printDocument1.PrinterSettings = printerSettings;
printDocument1.Print();
```

appreciate any help.